# global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can't get this operation to work. I am trying to merge some data into a table in another database via a database link (oradb2). When I am trying to do so, I am receiving a **ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation** error. I've tried altering the session and setting the global_names parameter to 'TRUE', but that doesn't solve the issue. Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

```
MERGE INTO sample_table@oradb2 X
USING
    (SELECT TO_VALUE,
            FROM_VALUE,
            to_date(data_date_dt, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as DATA_DATE_DT,
            UTC_HR_TS,
            DATA_TYPE_TX,
            VALUE_NB,
            LOCAL_TIME_TS
    FROM    V_SAMPLE_VIEW
 WHERE DATA_TYPE_TX = 'XML'
  ) A ON (
                X.FROM = A.FROM
                AND X.TO = A.TO
                AND X.TIMESTAMP = A.UTC_HR_TS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      SET X.VAL                = A.value_nb,
        X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = A.LOCAL_TIME_ts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT 
        (
          FROM,
          TO,
          DATE,
          TIMESTAMP,
          VAL,
          LOCAL_TIMESTAMP )
        VALUES   
         (A.FROM_VALUE
          A.TO_VALUE,
          A.data_date_dt,
          A.utc_hr_ts,
          A.value_nb,
          A.LOCAL_TIME_ts);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
RAISE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and share us the output

```
BEGIN
MERGE INTO sample_table@oradb2 X
USING
    (SELECT TO_VALUE,

            FROM_VALUE,
            to_date(data_date_dt, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as DATA_DATE_DT,
            UTC_HR_TS,
            DATA_TYPE_TX,
            VALUE_NB,
            LOCAL_TIME_TS
    FROM    V_SAMPLE_VIEW
 WHERE DATA_TYPE_TX = 'XML'
  ) A ON (
                X.FROM = A.FROM
                AND X.TO = A.TO
                AND X.TIMESTAMP = A.UTC_HR_TS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      SET X.VAL                = A.value_nb,
        X.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = A.LOCAL_TIME_ts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT 
        (
          FROM,
          TO,
          DATE,
          TIMESTAMP,
          VAL,
          LOCAL_TIMESTAMP )
        VALUES   
         (A.FROM_VALUE
          A.TO_VALUE,
          A.data_date_dt,
          A.utc_hr_ts,
          A.value_nb,
          A.LOCAL_TIME_ts);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace); 
end;
```

Comment: the message that I'm getting back is: ORA-02069: global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operationORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: I created an exact copy of the destination table using a (Create table xxx as select...) and was able to merge it into that exact table just fine. Any idea what may be the issue?